# Custom JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want to modify the code of the class [`AquaBarTabbedPaneUI`](http://www.jroller.com/DhilshukReddy/entry/custom_jtabbedpane) to work with `LEFT` tab placements.

`JTabbedPane` can be cutomized using the `BasicTabbedPaneUI`.
All that you need it do is write your own UI delegate class extending the `BasicTabbedPaneUI` class

```
public class MyTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI
{ }
```

I tried this `BasicTabbedPaneUI` [implementation](http://www.jroller.com/DhilshukReddy/resource/CustomTabbedPanes/AquaBarTabbedPaneUI.java)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class AquaBarTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

    private static final Insets NO_INSETS = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private ColorSet selectedColorSet;
    private ColorSet defaultColorSet;
    private ColorSet hoverColorSet;
    private boolean contentTopBorderDrawn = true;
    private Color lineColor = new Color(158, 158, 158);
    private Color dividerColor = new Color(200, 200, 200);
    private Insets contentInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    private int lastRollOverTab = -1;

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new AquaBarTabbedPaneUI();
    }

    public AquaBarTabbedPaneUI() {

        selectedColorSet = new ColorSet();
        selectedColorSet.topGradColor1 = new Color(233, 237, 248);
        selectedColorSet.topGradColor2 = new Color(158, 199, 240);

        selectedColorSet.bottomGradColor1 = new Color(112, 173, 239);
        selectedColorSet.bottomGradColor2 = new Color(183, 244, 253);

        defaultColorSet = new ColorSet();
        defaultColorSet.topGradColor1 = new Color(253, 253, 253);
        defaultColorSet.topGradColor2 = new Color(237, 237, 237);

        defaultColorSet.bottomGradColor1 = new Color(222, 222, 222);
        defaultColorSet.bottomGradColor2 = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        hoverColorSet = new ColorSet();
        hoverColorSet.topGradColor1 = new Color(244, 244, 244);
        hoverColorSet.topGradColor2 = new Color(223, 223, 223);

        hoverColorSet.bottomGradColor1 = new Color(211, 211, 211);
        hoverColorSet.bottomGradColor2 = new Color(235, 235, 235);

        maxTabHeight = 20;

        setContentInsets(0);
    }

    public void setContentTopBorderDrawn(boolean b) {
        contentTopBorderDrawn = b;
    }

    public void setContentInsets(Insets i) {
        contentInsets = i;
    }

    public void setContentInsets(int i) {
        contentInsets = new Insets(i, i, i, i);
    }

    public int getTabRunCount(JTabbedPane pane) {
        return 1;
    }

    protected void installDefaults() {
        super.installDefaults();

        RollOverListener l = new RollOverListener();
        tabPane.addMouseListener(l);
        tabPane.addMouseMotionListener(l);

        tabAreaInsets = NO_INSETS;
        tabInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    protected boolean scrollableTabLayoutEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    protected Insets getContentBorderInsets(int tabPlacement) {
        return contentInsets;
    }

    protected int calculateTabHeight(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex,
            int fontHeight) {
        return 21;
    }

    protected int calculateTabWidth(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex,
            FontMetrics metrics) {
        int w = super.calculateTabWidth(tabPlacement, tabIndex, metrics);
        int wid = metrics.charWidth('M');
        w += wid * 2;
        return w;
    }

    protected int calculateMaxTabHeight(int tabPlacement) {
        return 21;
    }

    protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, defaultColorSet.topGradColor1, 0,
                10, defaultColorSet.topGradColor2));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, tabPane.getWidth(), 10);

        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 10, defaultColorSet.bottomGradColor1,
                0, 21, defaultColorSet.bottomGradColor2));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 10, tabPane.getWidth(), 11);
        super.paintTabArea(g, tabPlacement, selectedIndex);

        if (contentTopBorderDrawn) {
            g2d.setColor(lineColor);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 20, tabPane.getWidth() - 1, 20);
        }
    }

    protected void paintTabBackground(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        ColorSet colorSet;

        Rectangle rect = rects[tabIndex];

        if (isSelected) {
            colorSet = selectedColorSet;
        } else if (getRolloverTab() == tabIndex) {
            colorSet = hoverColorSet;
        } else {
            colorSet = defaultColorSet;
        }

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int width = rect.width;
        int xpos = rect.x;
        if (tabIndex > 0) {
            width--;
            xpos++;
        }

        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(xpos, 0, colorSet.topGradColor1, xpos,
                10, colorSet.topGradColor2));
        g2d.fillRect(xpos, 0, width, 10);

        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 10, colorSet.bottomGradColor1, 0, 21,
                colorSet.bottomGradColor2));
        g2d.fillRect(xpos, 10, width, 11);

        if (contentTopBorderDrawn) {
            g2d.setColor(lineColor);
            g2d.drawLine(rect.x, 20, rect.x + rect.width - 1, 20);
        }
    }

    protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex,
            int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
        Rectangle rect = getTabBounds(tabIndex, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
        g.setColor(dividerColor);
        g.drawLine(rect.x + rect.width, 0, rect.x + rect.width, 20);
    }

    protected void paintContentBorderTopEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    }

    protected void paintContentBorderRightEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    protected void paintContentBorderLeftEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    protected void paintContentBorderBottomEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    protected void paintFocusIndicator(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
            Rectangle[] rects, int tabIndex, Rectangle iconRect,
            Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    protected int getTabLabelShiftY(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex,
            boolean isSelected) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ColorSet {
        Color topGradColor1;
        Color topGradColor2;

        Color bottomGradColor1;
        Color bottomGradColor2;
    }

    private class RollOverListener implements MouseMotionListener,
            MouseListener {

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            checkRollOver();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            checkRollOver();
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            tabPane.repaint();
        }

        private void checkRollOver() {
            int currentRollOver = getRolloverTab();
            if (currentRollOver != lastRollOverTab) {
                lastRollOverTab = currentRollOver;
                Rectangle tabsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tabPane.getWidth(), 20);
                tabPane.repaint(tabsRect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to customize my `JTabbedPane`

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setUI(new AquaBarTabbedPaneUI());
```

I get this

[image]

Sadly, most of the tabbed pane UI delegates work correctly only when the tab placement is set to TOP. The code needs to be tweaked in order for it to work with all tab placements (LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to modify the class AquaBarTabbedPaneUI to work with LEFT tab placements  JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
tabbedPane.setUI(new AquaBarTabbedPaneUI());